# How can I access the combobox column in grid view?

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, telerik-grid

Sorry if my question might be a little confusing. I'm using telerik R1 2020, how can I access the combobox in `Radgridview` by column name? I am creating autocomplete in `radgridview` using MySQL database, but it seems my code is working for all columns, I just want `column 0` to show autocomplete.

**This is my code snippet:**

```
private void RadGridView1_CellEditorInitialized(object sender, GridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GreatRetail_connect"].ConnectionString;
    MySqlConnection mysqlconn = new MySqlConnection(mainconn);
    string sqlquery = "SELECT Product_name FROM tb_stock_product";
    MySqlCommand sqlcmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlquery, mysqlconn);

    mysqlconn.Open();

    MySqlDataAdapter sdr = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sdr.Fill(dt);

    RadDropDownListEditor listEditor = this.radGridView1.ActiveEditor as RadDropDownListEditor;
    if (listEditor == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    RadDropDownListEditorElement editorElement = listEditor.EditorElement as RadDropDownListEditorElement;
    editorElement.DataSource = dt;
    editorElement.DisplayMember = "Product_name";
    editorElement.ValueMember = "Product_name";
    editorElement.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
    editorElement.DropDownStyle = RadDropDownStyle.DropDown;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I've found the solution to my previous question, maybe this can help those of you who have the same problem, or maybe there is a more concise or better program code than this ? 
this is the fixed code and it worked for me, just slightly adding a few lines :

```
if (sender is GridViewEditManager)
            if (((GridViewEditManager)sender).GridViewElement.CurrentColumn.Name == "column1")
            {
                RadDropDownListEditor listEditor = this.radGridView1.ActiveEditor as RadDropDownListEditor;

                if (listEditor == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                RadDropDownListEditorElement editorElement = listEditor.EditorElement as RadDropDownListEditorElement;
                editorElement.DataSource = dt;
                editorElement.DisplayMember = "Product_name";
                editorElement.ValueMember = "Product_name";
                editorElement.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
                editorElement.DropDownStyle = RadDropDownStyle.DropDown;
            }
```